# Does NSIS support external files?

Tags: installation, nsis

I basicaly want to have an external very large (bigger than 2gb) file next to my setup executable. To realize this, in the script I have tried the following:

```
File "$EXEDIR/verybigfile"
```

However, I got the following error:

File: "$EXEDIR/verybigfile" -> no files found.

Is it possible to do this in NSIS or do I require a plugin to realize this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `File` instruction cannot use variables like `$EXEDIR`, it needs the local path on your machine but you will hit the 2 GiB limit because these files are stored inside the installer.

If you are shipping a DVD or something like that you can use `CopyFiles /SILENT "$EXEDIR\files\*.*" "$InstDir"` to copy files from a DVD to the users system. This instruction does not support any kind of decompression, it is just a plain copy operation.

You need to use a plug-in to extract from [.ZIP](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/NsUnzip_plugin)/[.7z](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Nsis7z_plug-in) files.